# Two pickers in the same UIViewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, uipickerview

I am making an app where a user has the option to use two UIPickers in the same view controller. How can this be done. I am wanting one picker to display beach names and another to display animals living at the beach.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What concern do have for using two? Are you struggling with how to handle differentiating the pickers within the delegate methods?

Comment: Yes, i am unaware how you can set an array to the seperate pickers @IanMoses

Comment: Delegate methods include the UIPickerView as a parameter. You can assign each UIPicker a tag value and in each delegate method check the tag value . Something like: switch pickerView.tag { case pickerOneTagValue: // Do something here case pickerTwoTagValue: // Do something else here default: break }

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick guide to doing this:

1.Initialize pickers, and picker data sets in the class:

```
 var pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
 var pickerView2 = UIPickerView()

 var pickerView1Data: [String] = ["Waikiki", "Long Beach", ...]
 var pickerView2Data: [String] = ["Crab", "Seal", ...]
```

2.Set delegates, data sources, and tags (in viewDidLoad).

```
 pickerView1.dataSource = self
 pickerView1.delegate = self
 pickerView1.tag = 1

 pickerView2.dataSource = self
 pickerView2.delegate = self
 pickerView2.tag = 2
```

3.Set number of rows

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    var returnIndex: Int = 0

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        returnIndex = pickerView1Data.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        returnIndex = pickerView2Data.count
    }

    return returnIndex
}
```

4.Return data for each row

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    var returnRow: String!

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        returnRow = pickerView1Data[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        returnRow = pickerView2Data[row]
    }

    return returnRow
}
```

5.Capture pickerView selection

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.

    if pickerView.tag == 1 {

        beachTextField.text = pickerView1Data[row]

    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {

        animalTextField.text = pickerView2Data[row]

    }

}
```

Of course, this is on top of everything else you have to do to set up picker views, but this should be everything that needs to be taken care of for two picker views.